# Changing the active tab background color

Tags: html, mysql, css, jstl

I am generating the tabs dynamically using jstl.
When I click on the tab ,CSS style is applying for all the tabs that are generated dynamically not for the selected one.
My code is like this

```
<sql:setDataSource var="data" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample" user="root" password="sample" />
<sql:query dataSource="${data}" var="rs">SELECT DISTINCT component FROM `sample` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7 ;</sql:query>
<ul>
    <li><a href="LandingPage.jsp">Home</a>
    </li>
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${rs.rows}">
        <li> <a href="ComponentPage.jsp?name=${row.component}" id="onlink"> <c:out value="${row.component}" /></a>

        </li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

I have css code like this

```
#navbar {
    width: 660px;
}
#navbar #holder {
    height: 31px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    width: 1324px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
#navbar #holder ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navbar #holder ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    line-height: 10px;
    font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 105px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    background: #69F;
}
#navbar #holder ul li a:hover {
    background: #F90;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
#holder ul li a#onlink {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}
#holder ul li a#onlink:hover {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #69F;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
```

can anyone help me apply background colour for selected colour?

Answer (score 1):

You can get this done easily using jquery. Create a class active with the desire background color and using jQuery methods addClass and removeClass you can apply that class to specific tab on clicking it! Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to Your CSS Style,To change the background Color of your active tab

```
ul > li.active > a{
/*code here*/
background-color:#cccccc
}
```

or

```
ul > li:active > a{
/*code here*/
background-color:#cccccc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find out simple the solution.On click of li element, setting element name to url .
Form the url taking the value ,if it matches  just changing the background color.
It's a simple way it may be helpful for some one..

```
<script>
var full_url = document.URL; 
var url_array = full_url.split('=');
var name = url_array[url_array.length-1]; 


$("a:contains("+name+")").css("background-color", "white");



</script>
```